# How to solve React native version mismatch error

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently working on an expo (react native) project, then I stopped to install a new package (momentjs) , since then I cant continue , I keep getting this error. I've uninstalled this package still no way out.

[image]

This is my package.json below

```
  {


"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@simdanonline/react-native-rave": "^1.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-auth-session": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "react": "~16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "~16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.9",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.2.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my app.json below;

```
{


"expo": {
    "name": "simtwit",
    "slug": "simtwit",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "simtwit"
  }
}
```

My npm version 6.14.8

My node version is 12.18.3

Yarn 1.21.1

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Yes done that multiple times

Comment: And also restarted your machine?

Comment: @SimiloluwaOdeyemi I still think it is a cache issue, try cleaning simulators and terminal. Also restarting computer fixes sometimes

Comment: Cleared my cache and restarted my pc a few times, same error

Answer (score -1):

**Work for me:**

You have to close all your terminals, one of them is running a node process, which do not correspond to the same versions.